# Where can I find audio noise cancellation algorithms?

Tags: noise, noise-reduction

I want to implement an audio noise cancellation program.  Where can I find an algorithm for audio noise cancellation?

Answer (score 5):

If the signal you want to cancel is repetitive, then you can sample it, perform an FFT on the samples, do an inverse FFT and invert the resulting signal, then play it back synchronously during the next sampling period. This will work ok for low-frequency periodic noise, and to some extent for higher frequencies too - but the volume of space where the cancellation occurs decreases linearly with increasing frequency.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look into LMS filters (Least Mean Squared) and also how they are used in DSP. This is not easy, and I can't help you more unless you describe your environment.

Do you really mean cancellation or filtering? Cancellation is more related to actually generating noise cancellation frequencies from speakers/headsets.

for sound cancellation see

[Which algorithm is used for noise canceling in earphones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503562/which-algo-uses-for-noise-canceling-in-earphones)

Comment: I did mean cancelling.  I do want to generate the opposite of what I am sourcing.  Where can I find some example implementation or algorithm?

Comment: @user605957 see the link in the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The right term for what you are looking for is "active noise cancellation" I suggest to try searching for this term